# Spring , update value if not null

Tags: spring

I am working with Redmine API, and want to update an issue.

The issue has 30 variables, Subject, Description, Author, and Assignee ...

I have no problem updating the issue Subject and Description like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/issues/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> issueUpdate(@RequestBody ObjectNode json, @PathVariable int id) throws RedmineException, RuntimeException, IllegalArgumentException {
        String apiKey = json.get("API_KEY").asText();
        RedmineManager mgr = RedmineManagerFactory.createWithApiKey("http://localhost:3001/", apiKey);
        IssueManager issueManager = mgr.getIssueManager();
        Issue issue = issueManager.getIssueById(id);
        issue.setSubject(json.get("SUBJECT").asText())
            .setDescription(json.get("DESCRIPTION").asText())
            .update();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The problem with this way is I am only allowed to change these 2 values and I have to include, SUBJECT and DESCRIPTION in my JSON request body.

If SUBJECT is not in JSON, then it will be considered as null and I get `NullPointerException`.

I want to make something more flexible and elegant, to allow the change of each value, and if not exist, don't set to null but keep the old values.

something logical to this but a bit smarter

```java
if json.get("SUBJECT").asText() != null {
    issue.setSubject(json.get("SUBJECT").asText()) //set if mentioned
} else {
    issue.setSubject(issue.getSubject()) //set the old value
}
```

The idea is, now am available to have setSubject and all the other available setters in case it's mentioned in my JSON request or not.